# python conversion operator to string - overloading

Tags: python, string, vector, operator-overloading, overloading

How can I overloading the conversion operator into a string so that the Listing call returns the vector coordinates.

Listing:

```
w = Vector(5,6)
print(w)
```

Vector class:

class Vector:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        if isinstance(scalar, int) or isinstance(scalar, float):
            return Vector(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar)

    def __rmul__(self, scalar):
        return self.__mul__(scalar)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Depends on the `Vector` class, which you did not show us.

Comment: sorry for the problem, the class has been attached to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific, does `Vector` is a class you created?
If so, you need to add `__str__` method for printing usage.

You can read more about it in [what-is-the-str-method-in-python](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-str-method-in-python).

Example:

```
>>> class Vector:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x, self.y = x, y
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.x}, {self.y}"

>>> v = Vector(5,6)
>>> print(v)
5, 6
```

Comment: sorry for the problem, the class has been attached to the question

Comment: My answer is relevant for your example, you should override `__str__` method.
`def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.x}, {self.y}"`
 so when you call print on that object:
`print(w)`
you will get `5, 6`

Comment: thanks for the answer, when I try to solve the problem according to your advice, (str method) and calls the variable "w", the program fires but nothing displays.

Comment: That suppose to work, are you using older version of python than 3.x?
Anyway i edited my comment with an example so you can see what i meant, that works for me and prints `5, 6` as requested. Also, if you find my answers usefull you can upvote my answer :)